# How to read xml With .Net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2005

Please Go to : http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/SDN-List/Pages/default.aspx

And download SDALL.ZIP and extract it

And then you can find **SDN.XML**

My question is :

1. How to read it using C#.net VS2005 ?
2. Insert data in XML into Oracle Database ?

Comment: Is there something special about this XML?

Comment: @JohnSaunders : it's a complext XML .... and i can't read and loop for their children node...

Comment: I just took a look, and it's very simple XML.

Comment: @JohnSaunders : it's simple for you , but it's complex for me , inexperience xml reader .....

Comment: I meant that it is simple to the DataSet class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Try to load schema file from ZIP into DataSet
            // Then load XML File

```
DataSet dst = new DataSet();
    dst.ReadXmlSchema("C:\\sdn.xsd");
    dst.ReadXml("C:\\sdn.xml");

    // Now you have list of tables that contain all information you need.
    // For example punlishinformation
    DataTable dtPubInfo  = dst.Tables["publshInformation"];
    string publishdateInfo = dtPubInfo.Rows[0]["Publish_Date"].ToString();
    string recordCount = dtPubInfo.Rows[0]["Record_Count"].ToString();

    DataTable dtsdnEtry = dst.Tables["sdnentry"];
    // GEt all SDN entry
    DataColumnCollection colColumns = dtsdnEtry.Columns;
        foreach(DataRow dr in dtsdnEtry.Rows)         
                {
                    foreach(DataColumn dc in colColumns){
                            Console.WriteLine(dc.ColumnName + " - "  + dr[dc.ColumnName].ToString());
                        }
                    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");
                }
```

Comment: :Yes , you're right , but can you help me read their children as you wrote code above :
`foreach (DataRow dr in dtsdnEtry)
        {

        }
`
and table was designed in **SDN.XSD** in above link and in **SDNALL.ZIP**

Comment: For this specific requirement it will works. As there is XML and XSD schema of dataset available.

Comment: @JohnSaunders : SO , what is the best choice ?

Comment: @dotnetstep : So , how to read any table in table **SDNEntry**

Comment: Given that you're stuck with .NET 2.0, the best choice would be XmlDocument.

Comment: @dotnetstep : It can't get data from table **programlist**

Comment: @JohnSaunders : Hello Sir , can you help and give me the example code as dotnetstep .... i never use XmlDocument before.

Answer (score 1):

xmldocument can do this!
more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx